# Can't disable autolayout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, autolayout

I'm getting constraint break logs, that are totally logic, but I don't know why, because i've unchecked the "Use Auto Layout" check in all the xibs that are or will appear on the main window.

The constraint breaks are like this one:

```
    Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
    (
        "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x116f031b0 h=--& v=-&- H:[ListItemHoverView(10)]   (Names: ListItemHoverView:0x113d96660 )>",
        "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10b6f1680 h=-&- v=&-& H:[ListItemText]-(54)-|   (Names: ListItemHoverView:0x113d96660, ListItemText:0x113db29e0, '|':ListItemHoverView:0x113d96660 )>",
        "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10b674230 h=-&- v=&-& H:|-(37)-[ListItemText]   (Names: ListItemText:0x113db29e0, '|':ListItemHoverView:0x113d96660 )>"
    )

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x10b6f1680 h=-&- v=&-& H:[ListItemText]-(54)-|   (Names: ListItemHoverView:0x113d96660, ListItemText:0x113db29e0, '|':ListItemHoverView:0x113d96660 )>
```

All constraints are autogenerated from the autoresizing masks, but why? I've also unchecked every "Translates Masks Into Constraints" view's check. I'm missing something or having AL enabled in the other windows xibs affect the others too?

I'm in Xcode 4.6.3 and compiling for 10.8+ only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, using the `[NSTextView fittingSize]` method curiously enables the Auto Layout system in all your views (in the same window) regardless they are using it or not.